# OpenCV CalcPca input data

Tags: opencv, eigenvector, pca, eigen

I am trying to implement a face recognition training function with opencv, using "eigenfaces". I have the sample data, but I can't find any info on CalcPCA function arguments. All I know is that it takes data matrix, reference to average eigenface matrix, reference to eigen vector, and reference to eigen values matrix.

My question is, how should I pass the data from several test image matrices into the first argument of CalcPCA so I can get the average eigenface and vectors?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a good example: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/47627

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way: 
You have for example 10 Mat where each math represent an image.
Now you can create a new Mat that you can put into this new Mat the previus 10 Mat.
At this point use Mat.pushback(...) to insert the 10 Mat.
Hope this is helpful for you.
Marco